# Ignition wont turn on Volvo 2005 s40, existing key broke into ignition

Tags: volvo, ignition-key, ignition-switch, s40

I ordered a new remote key and the tech said that he cant program the key unless he can turn the ignition, is that true?

Or can we program the new key with the old existing code, i didnt lose the original key (metal lock key that we insert in the remote key) and the remote key itself. Its just broken and not readable
 The key broke in my ignition, it worked when i turned the whole thiing until my dad came and stuck a flat screw driver into the remaining part of the key thats stuck in it, and cracked way to deep in it and it then, didnt start after that incident, i could still turn it to start but eventually it just like stuck to off,( by the way i managed to take that little part out, after all of that.  and now it only says key error when inserting the old existing key part and the new remote key i bought from the dealer, does this mean its immobilized since like... Anyone can stick something similar and it obviously wont read since its like on lock down? anyone could stick something into it. Im wonderintG if the ignition is ok and reads something entering but since the code isnt programed the connection to even turn the ignition wont work?

The tech kinda made me feel like the only thing he could see being the error is the whole ignition and he cant program the new key unless she turns.

By the way my lights turn (inside floor when i get into the car and a door is opened)
My windows are stuck down, wont turn up, but i can lock and unlock the doors while im inside

I just want to program my new remote key to turn her on without having to pay for the whole ignition when i dont know if its just stuck nd the thief system alarm activated as soom as it broke the little part remaining in it that made the connection. i maybe thought when i got yhat ittle part ouyt.. it immobilized the car, windows wont go up and down you know? seems logic to me lol.

( Oh and i used superglue a couple of times in the entrance or the ignition to stick my remote ans remaining key back together could that be an option for her to not turn?)

Answer (score 1):

Your tech was correct - pairing a new key to an S40 involves turning the ignition. If it won't turn you can't pair the key to the car.

You can't reprogram the key itself (to imitate the old one) as it's they *car* that programs to the key not the other way around.

From what you describe about the sequence of events and how it not won't turn I think there's a good chance that there's damage to the ignition barrel. Could be from the superglue, could be from your dad jamming a screwdriver in, could be a combination of both.

I think you're just going to have to bite the bullet on this one and get the ignition replaced I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If the tech cannot follow the correct procedure to "pair" the new key with the car, then the old lock with the broken key part inside will have to be replaced.

The whole point of the security system is to prevent the car being taken easily - which means you have to get it working correctly.